# Visual Studio 2008 .Net CF 3.5 - Can't import SSH.NET library

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, .net-cf-3.5

I'm working on proprietary hardware that's locked to .Net 3.5 CF. When I try to add the SSH.NET reference, I'm getting the error below. Does anyone know what I need to do?

[image]

Comment: I just had same issue this week.  Open the csproj file in notepad and deleted the signing property.

Comment: Thank you but I can't seem to find it mine. What is the name of the property?

Comment: I don't remember.  I deleted it so I can't look it up.  The property was something like signing required.  It prevented the compiler from recompiling.  The error was also showing a pxf file (or something similar) that I could not see in the folder that I tried to delete.

Comment: Oh I see. Unfortunately, I can't see anything signing related in csproj and the signing is disabled in the project properties. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: What about the config file?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The issue, in the end, was with the project type I had selected. It was a custom project type (I'm working with proprietary and limited hardware) and that was affecting what libraries I could import. On a standard .net Framework project, it was referencing fine.

Answer (score 0):

The issue, in the end, was with the project type I had selected. It was a custom project type (I'm working with proprietary and limited hardware) and that was affecting what libraries I could import. On a standard .net Framework project, it was referencing fine.